# skflow.TensorFlowDNNRegressor parameters

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, skflow

I am new to skflow. With the following example code, I am able to initialize a neural network estimator.

```
regressor = skflow.TensorFlowDNNRegressor(
     hidden_units=[10, 10],
     steps=5000,
     learning_rate=0.1,
     batch_size=1)
```

I would like to know if these are the only input parameters for TensorFlowDNNRegressor or are there more parameters, which I can change? Could anyone please let me know where I can find this list of parameters? I am not able to find any documentation for it.

Comment: Documentation is coming soon. Stay tuned!

Comment: @YuanTang Thanks for the update. Looking forward for the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the documentation of this function [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/skflow/blob/929f924d3267b1a2ca3b39b1c39e6d42143464ff/g3doc/api_docs/python/estimators.md#class-skflowtensorflowdnnregressor-tensorflowdnnregressor). (not very clean format yet).

Here are the different parameters of the class:

```
skflow.TensorFlowDNNRegressor.__init__(
     hidden_units,
     n_classes=0,
     tf_master='',
     batch_size=32,
     steps=200,
     optimizer='SGD',
     learning_rate=0.1,
     tf_random_seed=42,
     continue_training=False,
     config_addon=None,
     verbose=1,
     max_to_keep=5,
     keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours=10000)
```

Comment: @Oliver Moindrot: Thanks for this link.